# How do I allow multiple downloads using anchor tags via a Java Servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, download, anchor

I am trying to download multiple pdf's from one click from the user (working in chrome). Once the user clicks on the relevant button a for loop is triggered to see how many documents need to be downloaded, for which each needs a download dialog. In the for loop I am mimicking a click for each pdf (this is done via javascript's click event).

The Java servlet code is below:

```
out.print("<a id='exportAchievement' style='display:none' href='" + tempFileName + "'download='" + pdfName + "'></a>");
out.print("<script>document.getElementById(\"exportAchievement\").click();</script>");
```

This works perfectly for one pdf, but as soon as I do two or more then each dialog that pops up uses the first pdf (the name and actual pdf is the same as the first one).

I checked if my variables are getting mixed up but, by use of print outs before and after the above code, it shows that the variables are correct.

My assumption is that the error is on the browser side because of the dialog working when one pdf needs to be downloaded, but I am stumped.

The relevant for loop is as follows:

```
// pdfs.length determines the number of pdf's to download
for (int j = 0; j < pdfs.length; j++) {
 if (pdfs[j].contains(".pdf")) {
  try {
   // build the path to the pdf
   achFile = sub.getPath() + "\\" + pdfs[j];
   // fills in relevant fields in the pdf
   if (PDFFill.fillPDF(achFile, student, user, context)) {
     String pdfName = student.getName() + "-" + achFile.substring(achFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
     String tempFileName = Protocol.ACHIEVEMENT_PATH + "/" + pdfName;
     out.print("<a id='exportAchievement' style='display:none' href='" + tempFileName + "' download='" + pdfName + "'></a>");
     out.print("<script>document.getElementById(\"exportAchievement\").click();</script>");
    } else {
      this.printWithNoty("Could not print PDF. " + achievement, "warning");
    }
   } catch (NullPointerException n) {
     System.out.println(n.getMessage());
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using a single `id` for all of the elements. IDs are unique. If you're using the same ID for everything, there's no way to discern between them and therefore you cannot expect multiple results.

```
<a id='exportAchievement' ...>
```

You can make that ID unique for each element and then it should work.

Comment: Thanks sxnine, I saw that as soon as I posted it, but couldn't answer because I'm a newbie. Works like a charm!